# FactoryGirl error: Factory not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Just beginning to learn testing... literally beginning.
Using rspec-rails, factory_girls_rails and fakers with Rails 4.

I have an Account and a User models. With Account:
 `has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'`

My first model test :

```
## /spec/models/account_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Account, :type => :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:account).should be_valid
  end
  it "is invalid without a name"
  it "is invalid without a subdomain"
  it "is invalid without a valid owner"
end
```

My 2 factories :

```
## /spec/factories/accounts.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    subdomain { Faker::Internet.domain_word }
    association :owner, factory: :user, strategy: :build
  end
end

## /spec/factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :owner, class: User do
    firstname { Faker::Name.first_name }
    lastname { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password(6) }
    role {"owner"}
  end
end
```

My test returns the following errors :

```
 1) Account has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:account).should be_valid
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: user
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:76:in `factory_by_name'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:12:in `run'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:31:in `association'
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your account factory is calling :user factory, which not exists.

change

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    subdomain { Faker::Internet.domain_word }
    association :owner, factory: :user, strategy: :build
  end
end
```

to

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    subdomain { Faker::Internet.domain_word }
    association :owner, factory: :owner, strategy: :build
  end
end
```